# Build a list of headers in current buffer

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to create a list of headers in the current `org-mode` buffer. Here is my code:

```
(setq m ())
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
      (add-to-list 'm '(nth 4 (org-heading-components)))))
```

This works fine if I take out the `while` statement. But for some reason, I can't get this to work past the first iteration.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The single quote prevents evaluating what is inside the list.  See the manual at the backquote section: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html  You may also wish to use `(list (nth ...))`

Comment: hmm... okay, I tried removing the 'm quote and the '(nth quote.. still no go. What am I missing?

Comment: Remove the single quote in front of `(nth`.

Comment: ah! Bingo! Actually, the syncher was to add (print m) so I could actually see that it worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Caution should be taken when creating new global variables with `setq`.  If there is no need to have the variable existing once the function has finished, then consider using `let` as in the example below.  `setq` can be used inside a function once a let-bound variable is defined, and the variable will cease  to exist once the function has finished.
2. Using a single quote in front of an open-parentheses makes Emacs think it is a list and that what is inside it should not be evaluated.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html
3. Placing the desired variable at the end of the function will return/throw the result of that variable.

```lisp
(let (m)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
      (add-to-list 'm (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
    m))
```